# Можно ли вкладывать один обработчик внутрь другого?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('bottom_line').childNodes[1].onmouseout = function () {
    document.getElementById('bottom').onmouseout = function () {}
}
```

Comment: в вашем случае вы что-то делаете неправильно, т.к. навешивете обработчик каждый раз, как курсор покидает `bottom_line`, мне кажется достаточно и одного раза

Comment: а есть лучшие решения в подобных ситуациях?

Comment: а вы ситуацию подробнее опишите

Comment: навешать обработчик на 1 элемент после срабатывания другого обработчика на другом элементе и при этом, чтобы навешивание обработчика каждый раз не делалось на первом при срабатывании другого обработчика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Только внутренний обработчик начнет обрабатывать события после того, как сработал внешний.

Comment: это правильно? так делать

Comment: Я не знаю. Код может быть правильный, но не подходить для вашей задачи.